# How to get ReativeCommand to get the latest CanExecute value?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveCollection which is bound to a WPF datagrid. One of the columns is a checkBox column.

The WPF form has a button that is bound to a ReactiveCommand.

What I am trying to do is only enable the button if all the checkboxes are ticked.

```
        var canHitContinueButton = this.WhenAny( x => x.MyCollection, ticks => ticks.Value.All(y => y.IsSelected));

        Continue = new ReactiveCommand(canHitContinueButton);

        Continue.Subscribe( doSomething => ());
```

It seems that the ReactiveCommand only checks the value when it is instantiated, but does not re-check the value when the items in the ReactiveCollection change. (The items in the ReactiveCollection are ReactiveObjects, so I assumed everything should be triggered automatically.)

How can I get the button to respond to changes to ReactiveObjects in the ReactiveCollection?

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally worked it out. I came up with two different approaches, but am not sure if they are the best way to go about it.

The first uses the ReactiveCollection.Changed event:

```
CanHitToggleButton = Customers.Changed.Select( _ => Customers.All(x => x.IsSelected)).StartWith(false);
```

This solution may be costly as the predicate gets executed every time the collection changes regardless of whether the change is checkbox related or not.

The other solution only gets triggered when a checkbox value gets changed.

```
CanHitToggleButton = Customers.ItemChanged.Where(x => x.PropertyName == "IsSelected").Select(_ => Customers.All(x => x.IsSelected)).StartWith(false);
```